Need help finding Green's function for Poisson's Equation with a Dirichlet boundary condition on a ball
My textbook covers setting up Green's function for Poisson's equation on a disk or radius, $a$, with a Dirichlet boundary condition, but does not cover the exact same problem for a spherical domain (or ball, $B_a(0)$ which is a ball of radius, $a$, centered at the origin). So I'm going to need guidance here without the assistance of a textbook or some dedicated source (unless someone can provide one for me to pick up which covers this). We have the Poisson's Equation
$$\nabla^2 u = \cases{1 & in $B_a(0)$ \\ 0 & outside} \\ u = 0 \text{ on boundary, } \partial B$$
, and to solve this, first need to need to find a Green's function which satisfies
$$\nabla^2G = \delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0) -\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*)\\ G(a,\theta,\phi,r_0,\theta_0,\phi_0) = 0$$
where $\textbf{r}_0* = \gamma \textbf{r}_0$ and $-\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*)$ is the negative image point which comes from method of images. The Green's function which would satisfy this Poisson's equation with a Dirichlet Boundary condition (with the negative image point) should be $$G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi |\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}-\frac{1}{4\pi |\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*|}+C$$.
Using the Dirichlet boundary condition: $C = -\Big(\frac{1}{4\pi (a^2+r_0^2-2ar_0\cos\beta)}-\frac{1}{4\pi(a^2+\gamma^2 r_0^2-2a\gamma r_0\cos\beta)}\Big) = -\frac{k}{4\pi}$, and now G is
$$G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\Big(\frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}-\frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*|}-k\Big)$$
Now all that's left is to determine $\gamma$, and that's where I'm not sure what to do. For the disk problem, $G=\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\Big(\frac{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}{|\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0|k}\Big)$, and a relationship between $\gamma$ and $k$ is created using $|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0| = k |\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0|$ where $|\textbf{r}| = a$ and we find that $k = \frac{1}{\gamma}$, and $\gamma = \frac{a^2}{r_0^2}$. What would I do instead to find $\gamma$ for the unit ball case for Poisson's Equation where $G = \frac{1}{4\pi}\Big(\frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}-\frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*|}-k\Big)$?

EDIT: Would the Green's function defined in this problem be the correct form for satisfying my problem?

You can exploit radial symmetry to reduce the problem to
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r} u\right)=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathrm B_a(\mathbf 0)}(r)\iff u=
\left{\begin{align}
&\frac{r^2}{6}-\frac{A}{r}+B, \enspace r<a\
&-\frac{A'}{r}+B', \enspace r>a
\end{align}\right.$$
So at least you know what the solution should look like if you solve it via Green's function.

@HugdeRoda Yep, that solution looks right. We can take solace in knowing what the solution's general form should be. I think I made some ground on trying to solve for $\gamma$ after I figured out how it worked in my textbook. It's a system of equations which arises from $\beta = \pi/2$ and $\beta = 0$, and the case for $\beta = 0$ becomes massively simplified by canceling out other terms due to the case for $\beta = \pi/2$. This isn't nearly as simple for the spherical case so we end up with a mess of algebra as can be seen in my most recent question.
